# c# datetime picker picked date save information

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

I want to make a agenda with date time picker but I have some trouble with it.
So I have a date time picker and 2 buttons, 1 button to insert a string (Inputbox) and the other one to show the string (messagebox). But I want to show the string by the selected date. So for example If I pick 5/15/2015 I want to insert a string in that date and then when I want to show the string it'll only show if the datepicker date is on 5/15/2015.

Thanks,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string inputdate { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inputdate = Interaction.InputBox("Voeg plan toe");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Date: " + dateTimePicker1.Text, "DateTimePicker", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

}
```

Lets say I select the date 5/15/2015 I want to Insert a string through a button(inputbox) example: "Birthday of John". with my button2(messagebox) I want to check what I have planned for 5/15/2015 so It'll show "Birthday of John".

Comment: Can you please show your work as well? What do you mean by _I want to insert a string in that date_ exactly? You wanna show your `DateTime` representation with an extra string?

Comment: And what do you want to show it exactly? Can you give an example output?

Answer (score 0):

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
```

This should help. As DateTimePicker works with value not with text taking its value and converting it to string for your message box.
Hope it helps